# Trouble with fill(url#) on loading inline SVG

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I don't know if anyone has already asked about something like this but I've been searching and I didn't find anything about this issue.

Some div is shown first and the others appear after a transition with JS. Inside one of these divs, I have an inline SVG. When the first div loads (the one that has the SVG inline), it appears OK like in this image:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-1un9u8DWH-UExQeXpQOXJBMzA/edit?usp=sharing

But, when the div that has the inline SVG appears only after some transition, it appears this way:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-1un9u8DWH-U0RHMnRoV3Y4OE0/edit?usp=sharing

The divs suffering transitions are the ones that hold the entire blocks (other than the parent div's block  with the svg inline). What seems to happen is that the fill of the svg that is called by `url(#idofgradient)` is not found, nor recognized. And the fill that only has `#F7F7F7` called works fine (the line part of the SVG on the middle of the image).

I have no idea what is happening in this case.

If anyone can help me, you have my thanks.

Comment: make a minimal test case then post the code - that's how Stackoverflow works

Comment: Yep jsfiddle example would be useful.

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary that they be inline svgs? Why not make a font with icoMoon? If you have not used svg much in the past I recommend not reinventing the wheel and using snap.svg

Answer (score 0):

It will be nice to see some code, but I think that the problem that you are having is related with the inline fill. Remove the inline fill and apply the fills with css (if you are making fill transitions).

```
.class{
fill:#aaa; 
}
.class:hover{
fill:#fff; 
}
```